# IQueryDescription SQL Query Returning Limited Records

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-desktop, sql

I created a SQL query that is working in SQL Management Studio, but as soon as I transfer the query into ArcMap's IQueryDescription to try and run it with a User Form, the results that I'm getting back are very limited and there is no clear pattern to the results it is returning. (409 records vs. 15 records)

I am even copying and pasting the query that works into the ArcObjects code, but I get a limited number of records back and no errors are thrown.

Has anyone run into this? What direction should I look for a solution?

I included the query below, although the query itself works just fine in SQL Management Studio.

```
SELECT CADDATA.CALLINDEX.NCALLHIST2, CADDATA.CALLINDEX.NHISTSEQUENCE, CADDATA.CALLINDEX.SZCALL, CADDATA.CALLINDEX.SZCALLTYPE, CADDATA.CALLINDEX.SZCALLDESC, CADDATA.CALLINDEX.SZGEOGROUP, CADDATA.CALLINDEX.SZPRIORITY, CADDATA.CALLINDEX.SZDISPOSITION, CADDATA.CALLINDEX.LTCREATED, CADDATA.CALLINDEX.LTENTERED, CADDATA.CALLINDEX.LTDISPATCHED, CADDATA.CALLINDEX.LTENROUTE, CADDATA.CALLINDEX.LTONSCENE, CASE WHEN RIGHT(SZLOCATION, CHARINDEX(',', SZLOCATION)) = '' THEN SZLOCATION ELSE LEFT(SZLOCATION, CHARINDEX(',', SZLOCATION) - 1) END AS Location, cast(LTCREATED as date)  as gedatedidid FROM CADDATA.CALLINDEX INNER JOIN CADDATA.CALLINDEX_MXSEQUNCE ON CADDATA.CALLINDEX.NCALLHIST1 = CADDATA.CALLINDEX_MXSEQUNCE.NCALLHIST1 AND CADDATA.CALLINDEX.NCALLHIST2 = CADDATA.CALLINDEX_MXSEQUNCE.NCALLHIST2 AND CADDATA.CALLINDEX.NHISTSEQUENCE = CADDATA.CALLINDEX_MXSEQUNCE.NHISTSEQUENCE WHERE (CADDATA.CALLINDEX.SZCALLTYPE IN ('1818', '1825', 'AH', 'BC', 'BS', 'BUS', 'CH', 'F', 'FP', 'PAT', 'PC', 'PW', 'SUB', 'TL', 'TS', 'TST', 'VHC', 'VP')) AND (CADDATA.CALLINDEX.SZGEOGROUP IN ('D1', 'D2', 'D3')) AND (cast(LTCREATED as date) >= '2013-6-4') AND (cast(LTCREATED as date) <= '2013-6-4')
```